# Transposing only one row into a column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to find the optimal way to go from the formatting you see in the first table below, to the one in the second table (format needs to be identical to table 2, cannot change a thing). As you can imagine, all "x" represent different values, and the data can be updated so this has to be dynamic.

The basic copy/transpose doesn't really work here, neither does a pivot table (unless I missed something there). There would be a way to do it "manually" with VLOOKUPs, but I'm pretty sure there is something more optimal than doing it that way, whether it is a formula I don't know or something in VBA.

Any ideas?

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would help here

Comment: The keyword to look for is "unpivot". Do some research and come back with your attempt if you get stuck or errors.

Comment: The tables wouldn't show up somehow, screenshots updated instead

Comment: To add to that, have a look at `PowerQuery()`. Just a few clicks [really](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPSbm.png).